# TEXT-to-COLUMN xlDMYFormat date format error

Tags: excel, vba, date, text-to-column

I'm trying to do a text to column using "!" Char.

```vb
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
  Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
  :="!", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
  1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 4), Array(9, 4), Array(10, 4), Array(11, 1)), _
  TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

The macro doesn't read xlDMYFormat (array(8, **4**) for example). It split my dates into two "groups" one goes to the right shifting MM and DD (11/02/2022 --> 02/11/2022) the other goes to the left like he didn't read it like a date (17/02/2022) because it can't be (02/17/2022).

I tried to use general format, change 4 with xlDMYFormat.